# how to disable column text in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

Avoid picture is my window form.

I want to set that the red rectangle is hide.

In conclusion, first column value is only index number.

if anybody know solution to my trouble, Please let me know the best way.

In advance, Thanks you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

To hide just the pointer in the row header you will need to do the following..

Add `RowPrePaint` and `CellFormatting` event handlers with the following code..

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.PaintCells(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

    e.PaintHeader(DataGridViewPaintParts.Background
        | DataGridViewPaintParts.Border
        | DataGridViewPaintParts.Focus
        | DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground
        | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

And you can add your index numbers with the following..

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = e.RowIndex.ToString();
}
```

[image]